# Return binary data along with additional information

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I'm requesting a file from server, reading it using `file_get_contents` and sending that data to client.  Is it possible to send additional information (like file id) along with image binary data?

I'm using Flash player to display this image. There is an option to use [flash loader object](http://blog.728media.com/2009/03/11/how-to-load-external-images-in-actionscript-30/)  and use url to load the image but that will mean that all the images must be public and I want to keep them in private.

Comment: How are you sending the data to the client?  What is the client doing with it?  Maybe you can add your metadata as a response header, or send your response as JSON (like `{name: 'test.jpg', data: '<binary or base64'd data>'}`).  Can you add some more info about your program?  There might be other solutions depending on what the client is doing with the response.

Comment: I updated question. I'm using Flash player to display the image. Also the data that I get from `file_get_contents`  is what I'm planning to pass back. This function returns file as a string.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to keep them in private"?

Comment: I don't want anyone to just browse to https://mysite.com/img/test.jpg  Others can start guessing file names etc.  These files should be private. So I'm thinking I can make a call to PHP script that will verify if the file id belongs to the user. Then it will read the file from disk and send image data back.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an Ajax session with client or straight forward browser client, or something else ?

If normal browser, not sure why you need to get_file_contents just link the file and adding file info like ID into html is simple

If Ajax, you could format the file info as a pre-determined length string pre-pended to the file contents and send it all as one block of data.
The client end could then strip off the known length of pre-pended characters to access file info and contents separately or any of dozens of other approaches

You need to clarify this question, I think

Added :

To solve problem of keeping files private you could try copying the files into a temporary folder, lot of server load but might solve your problem.  Eg instead of mysite.com/img/test.jpg   use   mysite.com/workfiles/userid_12345678_img_randombit.jpg        ........    track the files in a table and delete them after a certain time ..... bit of work but might solve your problem of privacy

Comment: Just reading the other answer and discussion which I cannot post to - so posting comment here.

Comment: To solve problem of keeping files private you could try copying the files into a temporary folder, lot of server load but might solve your problem.  Eg instead of mysite.com/img/test.jpg   use   mysite.com/workfiles/userid_12345678_img_randombit.jpg        ........    track the files in a table and delete them after a certain time ..... bit of work but might solve your problem of privacy

Comment: That is what I currently have. Now I need to return file data along with some metadata. I found some posts about attaching metadata to jpeg images but not pngs or gifs.

Answer (score 0):

Is a call to `exiftool` possible? You could set a key:value. See here for png and gif...
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/PNG.html#TextualData 
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GIF.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the "Content-Disposition" HTTP header. I don´t know how it could be done in PHP, but in .NET, you can do the folowing (may be you can figure out how to translate to PHP):

```
    this.Response.Clear();

    this.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    this.Response.Buffer = true;

    this.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.txt");

    Response.Write(_buffer);
    Response.End();
```